# What does the word 'port' mean pertaining to software development?

Tags: language-agnostic, definition

I'm reading a book on ASP.NET MVC, and it states:

> "NVelocity is a port of the Java Apache Velocity template engine, and NHaml is a port of the Ruby on Rails Haml engine".

What does the word 'port' mean in this instance?

Comment: In general, the `port` of an application is a re-write/conversion of an application existing in one OS or programming language to another OS or programming language. So NVelocity is a .Net version of the Java Velocity.

Comment: Awesome answer JScoobyCed!

Comment: BTW - Voting this question down? WTH?!

Comment: @ABogus lols I've seen many questions that are important to understand programming-related stuff, but downvoted or even closed forcefully. Maybe some ppl think the questions should be related to real code, but code is just code, like a language :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Porting (Software Engineering)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) entry on Wikipedia:

> In software engineering, porting is the process of adapting software so that an executable program [*or library*] can be created for a computing environment that is different from the one for which it was originally designed (e.g. [*different language*, ] different CPU, operating system, or third party library) ..
>
> .. the term "port" is derived from the Latin portare, meaning "to carry". When code is not compatible with a particular operating system [*or language*] or architecture, the code must be "carried" [or "ported"] to the new system.

Thus, "a port" is the result of "porting", and there are *many* different kinds of "ports".

In some cases a port might be *"only in spirit"* that heavily borrows from the *ideas* of the original implementation but otherwise shares no code; libraries often further diverge to take advantage of the target language features.

On the other hand, application ports - especially those that are designed to be portable between different "UNIX" environments - might share everything but the build process.

Comment: And some are just generated automagically from the original source, and everyone just hopes they works ^_^